# BeanCreationNotAllowedException after junit test in spring-boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-cloud

I got a Spring Boot project.
It can be startup successfully.
I added a test like this:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SopStart.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
public class Test{
    @Test
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("success!");
    }
}
```

The "success!" can be printed successfully. But at last I got an exception:

```
2017-10-25 17:00:42.481  INFO [bootstrap,,,] 7280 --- [      Thread-15] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@758d0555: startup date [Wed Oct 25 17:00:09 CST 2017]; parent: org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@75d4a80f
2017-10-25 17:00:42.492  WARN [bootstrap,,,] 7280 --- [      Thread-15] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's picking up the default `Application` class. Try defining your won configuration for the test class that excludes certain auto-configured beans including `EurekaClientAutoConfiguration` which is the main reason why your test is complaining.

You probably also don't need `@WebAppConfiguration`. You might even get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException`.

Here is an example,

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
//@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestExample.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Test.CustomConfiguration.class})
public class Test {

    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties
    @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
            JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,
            DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,  
            EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.class})
    static class CustomConfiguration {

    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("success!");
    }
}
```